# Apache2 Default Virtual Host in Virtualmin

Tags: redirect, apache2

I am raging here more than 3 hours how to make Apache2 work for me how I want.
I want when I access IP address directly, Apache2 serve me content from /var/www/html and not from virtualhost.

I tested everything including 000-default.conf file:

```
<VirtualHost *>
    ServerName 'baterka.xyz'
    ServerAlias 'MY_IP'
    DocumentRoot /var/www/html
</VirtualHost>
```

Nothing works. Apache2 (or Virtualmin) everytime use first VirtualHost in list but not my default file. How to make it works!

[image]

Comment: Define a VirtualHost for every doirectory you want to serve. Then add `ServerName example.com` and `ServerAlias w.x.y.z`

Comment: Omg, I am not idiot. I have everything setted up, But I want make direct IP access on /var/www/html, not automatically redirect to first vhost in row

Comment: Okay, then be an idiot and don't take the advice. I told you to add a ServerAlias, I said nothing about a redirect.

Comment: Why server alias to virtualhost what dont have any alias or domain name?

Comment: Your alias should be the IP. `ServerAlias 1.2.3.4`

Comment: and servername?

Comment: I have now `000-default.conf` with `ServerName baterka.xyz, ServerAlias IP and DocumentRoot /var/www/html`... Nothing happends. Still same problem

Comment: Are you reloading / restarting Apache after each config change?

Comment: @MattClark Sure :D